# Correct Usage of Names

Tags: word-usage

if the name has a junior e.g. Jose A. Ruiz, Jr. which comes first when the surname is asked first? Which is correct Ruiz, Jose Jr. A. or Ruiz, Jr. Jose A.?

Answer (score 6):

Neither of those are correct, the younger Jose A. Ruiz would be listed as

> Ruiz, Jose A. Jr.

if it was written in this lastname, firstname format.

He is the Junior 'Jose A.', so those names should be kept together.

Answer (score 3):

Post-nominals always come after the name (as the word *post-nominal* might indicate). Thus a name *Jose A Ruiz Jr,* when listed surname-first, would be

> Ruiz, Jose A Jr.

The same applies to names such as

> Hammerstein, Oscar II
>   Runcie, R A K, DD MC PC

Comment: Dealing with Robert Runcie's pre and post-nominals must be even more complex, because he is both a 'Right Honourable' (by virtue of membership of the Privy Council) and a 'Right Reverend'. I notice that one site gives him both a 'Rt Hon' before and a 'PC' after, appendage. Is that correct? What would his name look like with all bells and whistles attached? I'll have a go: 'The Rt Revd and Rt Hon. Baron Runcie DD, MC, PC.' Is that correct? Can we fit his Christian name into that? I don't think it is usual with peerages.

Comment: @WS2 How about The Rt Revd and Rt Hon Robert Alexander Kennedy, Baron Runcie of Cuddesdon, DD MC PC?

Comment: then you use 'that dude'.